# Laravel - How to ensure that order price is not less than product price in input field

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using Laravel-5.8 for a web application that involves dynamic input field. The project is based on sales Order.

Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'products';
  protected $fillable = [
          'name',
          'rate',
          'vat',
      ];
}

class Order extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'orders';
  protected $fillable = [
          'date',
          'customer_id',
          'workOrder_id',
          'details',
          'product_id',
          'rate',
          'vat',
          'quantity',
          'remaining',
      'amount',
      ];

  public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
  }

  public function product(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
  }
}
```

product_id in products is a foreign key to orders

Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $order = null;
    $products = Product::all('id','name');
    $customers = Customer::all('id','name');
    return view('pages.order.create', compact('order','products','customers'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'date'      => 'required',
        'customer_id'  => ['required', Rule::notIn(['','0'])],
        'workOrder_id'     => 'required|unique:orders',
    ]);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($request->product_id) ; $i++) { 

        $order =  new Order;

        $order->date = $request->date;
        $order->customer_id = $request->customer_id;
        $order->workOrder_id = $request->workOrder_id;
        $order->details = $request->details;
        $order->product_id = $request->product_id[$i];
        $order->rate = $request->rate[$i];
        $order->vat = $request->vat[$i];
        $order->quantity = $request->quantity[$i];
        $order->remaining = $request->quantity[$i];
        $order->amount = $request->quantity[$i] * $request->rate[$i];

        $order->save();
    }

    return redirect()
                ->route('order.index')
                ->with('success', 'Added Successfully');
}
```

In an order, a customer can have several products

[image: sales_order]

view

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card card-warning">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('order.store') }}">
                    @csrf
                    {{-- Date --}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date">
                            Date
                        </label>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="date" id="date" value="{{ old('date', optional($order)->date) }}">

                        @if ($errors->has('date'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('date') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    {{-- customer --}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="customer_id">Customer</label>
                        <select name="customer_id" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('customer_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="customer_id">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            @foreach($customers as $customer)
                            <option value="{{ $customer->id }}" {{old('customer_id', optional($order)->customer_id) == $customer->id ? 'selected':''}}>{{ $customer->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @if ($errors->has('customer_id'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('customer_id') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <button id="add_more" class="btn btn-info mt-4"><i class="fa fa-plus" title="Add More Product"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-11">
                            <div id="more_product">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        {{-- Product --}}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="product_id">Select Product</label>
                                            <select name="product_id[]" class="form-control" id="product_id" required="required">
                                                <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                                @forelse($products as $product)
                                                <option value="{{ $product->id }}" >
                                                    {{ $product->name }}
                                                </option>
                                                @empty
                                                <option value="">No Product Found</option>
                                                @endforelse
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        {{-- Rate --}}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="rate">
                                                Rate
                                            </label>
                                            <input type="number" min="0" step="any" class="form-control" name="rate[]" id="rate" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        {{-- Quantity --}}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="vat">
                                                Vat
                                            </label>

                                            <input type="number" min="0" step="any" class="form-control" name="vat[]" id="vat" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        {{-- Quantity --}}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="quantity">
                                                Quantity
                                            </label>

                                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" required="required">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {{-- workOrder_id --}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="workOrder_id">Work Order No</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('workOrder_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="workOrder_id" id="workOrder_id" value="{{ old('workOrder_id', optional($order)->workOrder_id) }}">

                        @if ($errors->has('workOrder_id'))
                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('workOrder_id') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    {{-- Payment Type --}}

            {{-- <div class="form-group">
                <label for="payment">Payment</label>
                <select name="payment" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('payment') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="payment">
                    <option value="">Select Payment</option>
                    <option value="1">Cash</option>
                    <option value="2">Due</option>
                </select>
                @if ($errors->has('payment'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('payment') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div> --}}


            {{-- Details --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="details">
                    Remarks
                </label>

                <textarea name="details" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('details') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="details" cols="30" rows="5">{{ old('details', optional($order)->details) }}</textarea>

                @if( $errors->has('details'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('details') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
            </div>

            {{-- Save --}}
            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        {{ __('Save') }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
{{-- jquery datepicker --}}
$( function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
});


$('#customer_id').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Customer',

    ajax: {
        url: '{!!URL::route('customer-autocomplete-search')!!}',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    theme: "bootstrap"
});

$('#product_id').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Product',

    ajax: {
        url: '{!!URL::route('product-autocomplete-search')!!}',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    theme: "bootstrap"
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 150;
    var wrapper         = $("#more_product");
    var add_button      = $("#add_more");

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3">{{-- Product --}}<div class="form-group"><label for="product_id">Select Product</label><select name="product_id[]" class="form-control product_id" id="product_id" required="required"><option value="">Select Product</option>@forelse($products as $product)<option value="{{ $product->id }}" >{{ $product->name }}</option>@empty<option value="">No Product Found</option>@endforelse </select></div></div><div class="col-md-3">{{-- Rate --}}<div class="form-group"><label for="rate">Rate</label><input type="number" min="0" step="any" class="form-control" name="rate[]" id="rate" required="required"></div></div><div class="col-md-2">{{-- vat --}}<div class="form-group"><label for="vat">Vat</label><input type="number" min="0" step="any" class="form-control" name="vat[]" id="vat" required="required"></div></div><div class="col-md-3">{{-- Quantity --}}<div class="form-group"><label for="quantity">Quantity</label><input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" required="required"></div></div><div class="col-sm-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field"><button style="margin-top: 30px;" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-minus" title="Remove Item"></i></button></a></div></div>');

            $('.product_id').select2({
                placeholder: 'Select Product',

                ajax: {
                    url: '{!!URL::route('product-autocomplete-search')!!}',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: data
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                theme: "bootstrap"
            });
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent().parent('div').remove(); 
        x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

I have been on this for days. What I want to achieve is that as the User enter the rate on order on a particular product, the system should compare it with the rate in products.

If the rate on order is less than that in product, the system should display an error message to the user explaining the problem.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you have one-to-many relationship between `Order` and `Product`. If you want to have multiple products per `Order`, you don't need `product_id` field - you need a pivot table to create many-to-many relationship. Is there any particular reason why you want to have `Rate` field for the product when associating with `Order` - is it to be able to specify higher price than product associated one?

Comment: @SebastianSulinski - Yes, one-to-many. The Rate in the product is the cost price (the amount the store-keeper bought the product). While Rate in the order table is the selling price. No, I dont need one-to-many. The reason is to hinder (disallow) the user from entering a value below the cost price.  Kindly assist

Comment: Sorry, is it many-to-many then?

Comment: @SebastianSulinski - No, it is one-to-many. You can see from the Model and Controller. One Order consists of Many products.Thanks.      public function product(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
  }

Comment: Ok, because you said “In an order, a customer can have several products” and you provide option to add more products so I’m trying to figure out the structure here. If it’s just one product per order then that’s fine, but then what would be the purpose of the plus button - if you could please elaborate.

Comment: I have updated the diagram. Sorry, a customer can have several products. But that's not the concern. An order could have several products placed by a customer. That is working perfectly, I have tested it. You can see that from the code. But where the concern is, is that on each product the customer selects the rate he enters must be compared with the rate in the product table and should not be less than it. For example, if he selects product-A and the price of Product a is 200, then he cannot enter anything less than 200. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I'll try to recreate it locally and see what I can come up with, but I can see you don't have client validation so it will only be validated on the server - meaning you will only know that the entered value is invalid when the request hits the server - I hope that's what you're after.

Comment: Is it possible to tell the user before he submits. Thanks

Comment: You would have to have some sort of form validation using javascript. Doing it with jQuery would be cumbersome. If you were using some framework like for instance VueJs, this could be easier to achieve.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Whichever way you can help. I've been on it for days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I've come up. As explained earlier, this only provides server side validation as from what I can see you do not have any client side one.

First thing I did was to convert validation in the controller to a Request injected to the `store` method. I called it `StoreOrderRequest`

**App\Http\Requests\StoreOrderRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Order;
use App\Product;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Class StoreOrderRequest
 *
 * @package App\Http\Requests
 *
 * @property string $date
 * @property int $customer_id
 * @property int $workOrder_id
 * @property array $product_id
 * @property array $rate
 * @property array $vat
 * @property array $quantity
 */
class StoreOrderRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'date' => 'required',
            'customer_id' => [
                'required',
                'exists:customers,id',
            ],
            'workOrder_id' => [
                'required',
                'unique:orders',
            ],
            'details' => 'present',
            'product_id' => 'array',
            'rate' => 'array',
            'vat' => 'array',
            'quantity' => 'array',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the data for validation.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareForValidation(): void
    {
        $this->redirect = route('order');

        $this->validator = $this->getValidatorInstance();

        $this->validator->after(function (Validator $validator) {

            $products = Product::whereIn('id', $this->product_id)->get();

            foreach ($this->product_id as $key => $id) {

                $rate = $products->firstWhere('id', $id)->rate;

                if ($rate < $this->rate[$key]) {
                    continue;
                }

                $validator->errors()->add(
                    'rate.'.$key,
                    __(
                        'validation.min.numeric',
                        [
                            'attribute' => 'rate',
                            'min' => $rate
                        ]
                    )
                );
            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * Create orders.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function save(): void
    {
        $orders = collect($this->product_id)
            ->map(function (int $product_id, int $index) {
                return array_merge(
                    $this->only([
                        'date',
                        'customer_id',
                        'workOrder_id',
                        'details',
                    ]),
                    [
                        'product_id' => $this->product_id,
                        'rate' => $rate = $this->rate[$index],
                        'vat' => $this->vat[$index],
                        'quantity' => $qty = $this->quantity[$index],
                        'remaining' => $qty,
                        'amount' => $qty * $rate,
                    ]
                );
            });

        Order::insert($orders->toArray());
    }
}
```

You'll see that I've made use of the `prepareForValidation` method, which allowed us to register the `after` validation hooks. These check each product rate and if it's less than the corresponding `Product` record, it will add the error for its index to the error bag.

(Please note I've overriden the default `redirect` property to work with my test - you probably won't need that line if you're just going back to the previous page).

I've also created the `save` method that saves all these orders.

With all this, we are now able to skim your `OrderController::store` method significantly:

**OrderController**

```
/**
 * Store new record.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\StoreOrderRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function store(StoreOrderRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $request->save();

    return redirect()
        ->route('order')
        ->with('success', 'Added Successfully');
}
```

And here's the corresponding test to make sure everything above works as expected:

**Tests\Feature\ProductOrderTest**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Order;
use App\Product;
use App\Customer;
use Tests\TestCase;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ProductOrderTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function validation_fails_with_product_rate_lower_than_original_product_price()
    {
        $customer = factory(Customer::class)->create();

        $product_1 = factory(Product::class)->create(['rate' => 20.50]);
        $product_2 = factory(Product::class)->create(['rate' => 95.67]);

        $this->assertCount(0, Order::all());


        $response = $this->post(route('order.store'), [
            'date' => now(),
            'customer_id' => $customer->id,
            'workOrder_id' => 1,
            'details' => 'Order details',
            'product_id' => [
                0 => $product_1->id,
                1 => $product_2->id,
            ],
            'rate' => [
                0 => 20.49,
                1 => 95.66,
            ],
            'vat' => [
                0 => round(20.49 * 0.20),
                1 => round(95.66 * 0.20),
            ],
            'quantity' => [
                0 => 1,
                1 => 1,
            ],
        ]);


        $response->assertRedirect(route('order'));

        $response->assertSessionMissing('success');

        $response->assertSessionHasErrors([
            'rate.0' => __('validation.min.numeric', [
                'attribute' => 'rate',
                'min' => 20.50
            ]),
            'rate.1' => __('validation.min.numeric', [
                'attribute' => 'rate',
                'min' => 95.67
            ]),
        ]);

        $this->assertCount(0, Order::all());
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function saves_order_with_valid_request()
    {
        $customer = factory(Customer::class)->create();

        $product_1 = factory(Product::class)->create(['rate' => 20.50]);
        $product_2 = factory(Product::class)->create(['rate' => 95.67]);

        $this->assertCount(0, Order::all());


        $response = $this->post(route('order.store'), [
            'date' => $date = now(),
            'customer_id' => $customer->id,
            'workOrder_id' => 1,
            'details' => 'Order details',
            'product_id' => [
                0 => $product_1->id,
                1 => $product_2->id,
            ],
            'rate' => [
                0 => 20.50,
                1 => 95.68,
            ],
            'vat' => [
                0 => round(20.50 * 0.20),
                1 => round(95.68 * 0.20),
            ],
            'quantity' => [
                0 => 1,
                1 => 1,
            ],
        ]);

        $response->assertRedirect(route('order'));

        $response->assertSessionHas('success', 'Added Successfully');

        $response->assertSessionDoesntHaveErrors();

        $this->assertCount(2, Order::all());

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('orders', [
            'date' => $date = now(),
            'customer_id' => $customer->id,
            'workOrder_id' => 1,
            'details' => 'Order details',
            'product_id' => $product_1->id,
            'rate' => 20.50,
            'vat' => round(20.50 * 0.20),
            'quantity' => 1,
            'remaining' => 1,
            'amount' => 20.50,
        ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('orders', [
            'date' => $date = now(),
            'customer_id' => $customer->id,
            'workOrder_id' => 1,
            'details' => 'Order details',
            'product_id' => $product_2->id,
            'rate' => 95.68,
            'vat' => round(95.68 * 0.20),
            'quantity' => 1,
            'remaining' => 1,
            'amount' => 95.68,
        ]);
    }
}
```